# Save image to node via form API

Tags: 7, forms

I am having trouble figuring out how to attach an uploaded image to a node in my form submit handler. I've been searching for a while now and nothing I've tried has worked. For instance:

```
$image = $form_state['storage']['image'];
unset($form_state['storage']['image']);
$image->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file = file_save($image);
$node->field_image['und'][0] = $file;
```

does not work.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly you need `$node->field_image['und'][0] = (array) $file;` and then you need to call `node_save($node);` after that.

Comment: @Jaypan I have tried that as well. I've been at this for over an hour, and have tried basically everything on Google.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @Jaypan Well, first off, I get "undefined index storage" so I've replaced that with ["values"]["image"]. But the uploaded image does not get attached to the node. I've tried a `var_dump($form_state['values']['image'])` (as well as ['storage']), but that gives me an empty string. And no matter what I do, I don't get an image attached to the node.

Comment: What is the form element defined as? If it's type 'file', then the uploaded data will be part of the $_FILES global. Usually it's better to create the element as type 'managed_file' though, in which case the value in the submit will be the file ID of the uploaded file, and you don't need to touch the $_FILES global.

Comment: @Jaypan Ahhh thank you! Once I changed it to 'managed_file' it started working.

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this but this link should be a good start. [File Load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load/7.x)

Assuming $form_state['storage']['image'] is the image's fid, what you may want to do is.

```
$image = $form_state['storage']['image'];
$file = file_load($image);

// Change status to permanent.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

// Save.
file_save($file);

// add image back
$node->field_image['und'][0] = $image;
```

Depending on what your doing you may want to add the file to the usage table. Details here.
[File Usage Add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7.x)

Comment: Thank you. This finally worked after switching to 'managed_file' as the type.

Comment: No problem, I forgot about that being necessary. Glad you worked it out.